# Android Studio app: Failure to Assemble APK after updating studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I updated my Android Studio to 3.1 and then I changed the package name of my app from "jake.stackitupreimported" to "basic.games".  Once that was completed, I clicked "gradle" to the right >>root>>tasks>>build>>assemble; then I got this failure notification below.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this so I can assemble my app? Thanks!!!

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: make sure to clean the project (menu Build->clean project), and then rebuild the project

Comment: when i click gradle to the right on the screen>>root>>tasks>>build>> assemble, it still comes up with that error even after cleaning the project. is this action needed to create an apk so that my app can be used on android phones?